# how to add 'selected' attribute in <li> using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to add 'selected' attribute by comparing the value between `<li></li>`

```
<ul class="list">
<li data-value="0" class="option" selected>All Categories</li>
<li data-value="75" class="option">eBriefs</li>
<li data-value="74" class="option">Hawkeye-articles</li>
<li data-value="1" class="option">Hhhhh</li>
<li data-value="93" class="option focus">Hyphen-Newsletter</li>
<li data-value="95" class="option">Infographics</li>
<li data-value="76" class="option">News</li>
<li data-value="134" class="option">Podcast-webinar</li>
<li data-value="79" class="option">Podcasts</li>
<li data-value="81" class="option">Success Stories</li>
<li data-value="94" class="option">Videos</li>
<li data-value="77" class="option">Webinars</li>
<li data-value="83" class="option">Whitepapers</li>
</ul>
```

For example, I wanted to add 'selected' attribute to Podcasts, and removing `selected` from `All Categories` option.

Like, I wanted to check if the text between `<li></li>` is `Podcasts` then put selected attribute in `<li data-value="79" class="option">Podcasts</li>`

and make it

`<li data-value="79" class="option" selected>Podcasts</li>`

Major goal is to put selected attribute by comparing value `<li></li>`

How can I do it with jQuery or javascript?

Comment: you are confusing an `<ul>` with a `<select>`

Comment: Where does "podcasts" come from? If you add that detail it's (probably) relatively easy to make the suggestions more easily fit your wider use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery and Vanilla js examples to demonstrate what you want. Also there are other solutions resembling this solution as you can see on other answers.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li data-value="0" class="option" selected>All Categories</li>
    <li data-value="75" class="option">eBriefs</li>
    <li data-value="74" class="option">Hawkeye-articles</li>
    <li data-value="1" class="option">Hhhhh</li>
    <li data-value="93" class="option focus">Hyphen-Newsletter</li>
    <li data-value="95" class="option">Infographics</li>
    <li data-value="76" class="option">News</li>
    <li data-value="134" class="option">Podcast-webinar</li>
    <li data-value="79" class="option">Podcasts</li>
    <li data-value="81" class="option">Success Stories</li>
    <li data-value="94" class="option">Videos</li>
    <li data-value="77" class="option">Webinars</li>
    <li data-value="83" class="option">Whitepapers</li>
</ul>
<script>
    //Vanilla js
    document.querySelectorAll('.option').forEach(elem => {
        if (elem.innerHTML == 'Podcasts')
        elem.setAttribute('selected', '')
        else
        elem.removeAttribute('selected')
    })
    //Jquery
    const selectIt = $('.option:contains("Podcasts")')
    if (selectIt)
        selectIt.attr('selected', '')
    else
        selectIt.removeAttr('selected')
</script>
```

Comment: FYI `:contains("Podcasts")` does a partial match (contains, not equals), so if another was, for example, "Archived-Podcasts" it would be included in `selectIt`.

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0].children[0].removeAttribute("selected")`

`document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0].children[1].setAttribute("selected", '')`

children[0] is the first element
children[1] is the second and so on

Answer (score 1):

`selected` isn't [a permissible attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attributes) on a list item so I suggest making `selected` another class, and then using a function to toggle that class on/off.

```js
// Cache the list items, and coerce them to an array
// so we can use array methods on it
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.option')];

// Accepts a list, and a string of text
function toggleSelect(list, text) {

  // `find` the list item that has textContent matching
  // the text argument
  const found = list.find(li => li.textContent === text);

  // And if it finds it, toggle its class
  if (found) found.classList.toggle('selected');
}

// Using a timeout here so you can see
// the result more clearly
setTimeout(() => {
  toggleSelect(list, 'All Categories');
  toggleSelect(list, 'Podcasts');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.selected { color: red; }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li data-value="0" class="option selected">All Categories</li>
  <li data-value="75" class="option">eBriefs</li>
  <li data-value="74" class="option">Hawkeye-articles</li>
  <li data-value="1" class="option">Hhhhh</li>
  <li data-value="93" class="option focus">Hyphen-Newsletter</li>
  <li data-value="95" class="option">Infographics</li>
  <li data-value="76" class="option">News</li>
  <li data-value="134" class="option">Podcast-webinar</li>
  <li data-value="79" class="option">Podcasts</li>
  <li data-value="81" class="option">Success Stories</li>
  <li data-value="94" class="option">Videos</li>
  <li data-value="77" class="option">Webinars</li>
  <li data-value="83" class="option">Whitepapers</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.childNodes` to get all children. Then iterate over them and remove the attribute selected with `element.removeAttribute`.

You can use `element.textContent` to get the content of the `<li>` element. If it fits your search you can then use `element.setAttribute()` to mark it as selected.

I prepared a small example of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/xLfp8z57/1/

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li data-value="0" class="option" selected>All Categories</li>
  <li data-value="75" class="option">eBriefs</li>
  <li data-value="74" class="option">Hawkeye-articles</li>
  <li data-value="1" class="option">Hhhhh</li>
  <li data-value="93" class="option focus">Hyphen-Newsletter</li>
  <li data-value="95" class="option">Infographics</li>
  <li data-value="76" class="option">News</li>
  <li data-value="134" class="option">Podcast-webinar</li>
  <li data-value="79" class="option">Podcasts</li>
  <li data-value="81" class="option">Success Stories</li>
  <li data-value="94" class="option">Videos</li>
  <li data-value="77" class="option">Webinars</li>
  <li data-value="83" class="option">Whitepapers</li>
</ul>

<button id="btn">unselect all</button>

<button id="btn2">select all ending with 'r'</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", event => unselectAll());
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", event => selectSpecific());

function unselectAll() {
  let list = document.querySelector(".list")

  list.childNodes.forEach(item => {
    if (item.tagName === 'LI') {
      item.removeAttribute("selected")
    }
  });
}

function selectSpecific() {
  let list = document.querySelector(".list")

  list.childNodes.forEach(item => {
    if (item.tagName === 'LI' && item.textContent.endsWith("r")) {
      item.setAttribute("selected", "");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
li[selected]{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think `element.childNotes` is probably a typo; did you mean `element.childNodes`?

Comment: Please include the jsfiddle code as a snippet in your answer.   External links are discouraged.  Though, to be clear, this isn't a link-only-answer as you have an answer description - just easier to have the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, `.removeAttr()` will remove an existing attribute and `.attr("name", "")` will add a *flag* attribute:

You can use `$("[attribute]")` to select elements with a specific attribute, giving a succinct:

```
$("[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
$(".list .option").filter((i, e) => $(e).text() == "Podcasts").attr("selected", "")
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
$(".list .option").filter((i, e) => $(e).text() == "Podcasts").attr("selected", "")
```

```css
[selected] { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li data-value="0" class="option" selected>All Categories</li>
  <li data-value="75" class="option">eBriefs</li>
  <li data-value="74" class="option">Hawkeye-articles</li>
  <li data-value="1" class="option">Hhhhh</li>
  <li data-value="93" class="option focus">Hyphen-Newsletter</li>
  <li data-value="95" class="option">Infographics</li>
  <li data-value="76" class="option">News</li>
  <li data-value="134" class="option">Podcast-webinar</li>
  <li data-value="79" class="option">Podcasts</li>
  <li data-value="81" class="option">Success Stories</li>
  <li data-value="94" class="option">Videos</li>
  <li data-value="77" class="option">Webinars</li>
  <li data-value="83" class="option">Whitepapers</li>
</ul>
```

As noted elsewhere, `selected` should ideally not be added as an attribute to a `li`.  Using a class should have the same affect, though there may be some other reason for using an attribute not mentioned in the question.